# A* path finding algo sometimes doesn't find path even when there is one (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I made a custom path A* Pathfinding Algorithm in Python, but it sometimes doesn't even find path to the end node even when there clearly is a path. Here is my implementation.

```
# this is my Node class. I am representing the whole maze as a matrix and every cell
# of that matrix is a Node Object

class Node():
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
        self.isWall = False
        self.isOpen = None
        self.f = 0
        self.g = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.neighbors = []
        self.previous = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'< i = {self.i}, j = {self.j}, previous = {self.previous} >'

    def add_neighbors(self, grid, diagonal):
        i = self.i
        j = self.j

        if i > 0:
            self.neighbors.append(grid[i - 1][j])

        if i < len(grid) - 1:
            self.neighbors.append(grid[i + 1][j])


        if j > 0:
            self.neighbors.append(grid[i][j - 1])

        if j < len(grid) - 1:
            self.neighbors.append(grid[i][j + 1])

        if diagonal:
            # for diagonal neighbors

            # down and right
            if i < len(grid) - 1 and j < len(grid) - 1:
                self.neighbors.append(grid[i + 1][j + 1])

            # up and right
            if i > 0 and j < len(grid) - 1:
                self.neighbors.append(grid[i - 1][j + 1])

            #down and left
            if i < len(grid) - 1 and j > 0:
                self.neighbors.append(grid[i + 1][j - 1])

            #up and left
            if i > 0 and j > 0:
                self.neighbors.append(grid[i - 1][j - 1])
```

iterate through and set up the nodes

```
def make_grid(length):
    main_grid = []
    for i in range(length):
        lst = []
        
        for j in range(length):
            node = Node(i, j)

            # 30 % chance that the current node will be set as a wall
            if random.randrange(1, 101) > 70 and i != 0 and j != 0: node.isWall = True

            lst.append(node)

        main_grid.append(lst)


    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(length):
            main_grid[i][j].add_neighbors(main_grid, diagonal = True)
 

    return main_grid

# Below is how the above function 'make_grid' is called

# making the grid
grid_len = 25
main_grid = make_grid(grid_len)
path = [] # to reconstruct the optimal path
```

Below is the HScore function I'm using

```
# HScore function

def getHScore(node, endNode):
    return sqrt(abs(node.i - endNode.i)**2 + abs(node.j - endNode.j)**2)
```

Below is the actual Algorithm implementation

```
# A* PATHFINDING ALGORITHM

def aStar(start_node, end_node):
    # node.f = node.g + node.h
    # node.g = distance of current node from the starting node
    # node.h = distance of current node from the end node

    start_node.g = 0
    start_node.h = getHScore(start_node, end_node)
    start_node.f = start_node.g + start_node.h
    open_set = [start_node]
    closed_set = []

    if start_node.isWall:
        print("The start node is a wall")
        return

    while True:
        
        if len(open_set) < 1:
            print('No Solutions Found')
            break

        current_node = open_set[0]

        for node in open_set:
            if node.f < current_node.f:
                current_node = node
                current_node.isOpen = True

        # print(f'current_node = {current_node.i, current_node.j}', end = " ")

        if current_node == end_node:
            temp = end_node
            path.append(temp)

            while temp.previous is not None:
                path.append(temp.previous)
                temp = temp.previous

            print("DONE")
            colorFinalPath(main_grid)
            break

        # current_node.isPath = True
        current_node.isOpen = False

        open_set.remove(current_node)
        closed_set.append(current_node)

        for neighbor in current_node.neighbors:
            # assuming 1 as the distance btw two neighbouring points that aren't diagonally
            # neighbors

            # need to add 1.14 if neighbor is diagonal. add propery to node class to check if neighbor is diagonal

            if neighbor in closed_set:
                continue

            tempG = current_node.g + getHScore(current_node, neighbor)

            if neighbor not in open_set and not neighbor.isWall:
                neighbor.g = tempG
                open_set.append(neighbor)
                neighbor.isOpen = True
                neighbor.previous = current_node

            if tempG >= neighbor.g:
                continue # there is no better path
            
            # neighbor was found in the open set, so we check if we can get to it in 
            # a better way as tempG is now less than neighbor.g

            neighbor.previous = current_node
            neighbor.g = tempG
            neighbor.h = getHScore(neighbor, end_node)
            neighbor.f = neighbor.g + neighbor.h

        show_steps(main_grid, start_node, end_node)
```

Some Screen shots
In the third picture there is clearly a path between the starting Node (top left) and the end Node (bottom right) but it doesn't find any solutions.

Please tell me what's wrong with my implementation. Any help is appreciated

[image: AStar Algo Outputs. Blue line is the path found. Red spots are closed nodes. Green spots are open nodes]

Comment: Is that the whole `Node` class?

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but did you enable diagonal?

Comment: @harold yes that is the entire node class

Comment: @NathanWride yes I did. In the node class I am adding diagonal neighbors

Comment: Can you show the code where you iterate through and set up the nodes?

Comment: @NathanWride I edited the post to include that function that sets up the Nodes

Comment: I can't see any glaringly obvious causes. I would try reducing the grid and then print debug information, you should be able to run through the output and see where the issue occurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some issues in this piece of code:

```
tempG = current_node.g + getHScore(current_node, neighbor)

if neighbor not in open_set and not neighbor.isWall:
    neighbor.g = tempG
    open_set.append(neighbor)
    neighbor.isOpen = True
    neighbor.previous = current_node

if tempG >= neighbor.g:
    continue # there is no better path
```

- When the neighbor is a wall, you should skip it immediately. So add at the top:

  ```
    if neighbor.isWall:
        continue
  ```

  This also means you can remove the wall check from the `if` you already had
- The condition to check there is no better path will also be true when you just had set the `g` component for the first time, i.e. when the middle part was executed. This should not happen. So change that `if` to an `elif`:

  ```
    if neighbor not in open_set:
         # ... etc ...
    elif tempG >= neighbor.g:
        continue # there is no better path
  ```
- Your `make_grid` code could mark the end node as a wall. You do not reject that situation, and then your code will `continue` and skip that as a neighbor to put in the open set. It is not clear from your image whether this happened, as you colored the ending node in blue.

Then, less of a problem, but you will sometimes call `getHScore` multiple times for the same node. Obviously, that function will return the same value for each of those calls. So you could improve on that. For example, by moving that line in an `if` condition:

```
if neighbor.h == 0:
    neighbor.h = getHScore(neighbor, end_node)
```

I don't know whether it was intended but a diagonal step gets a cost of 2 (1²+1²), and it has no advantage over a 2-step walk to that same square. This is a tiny detail as you would visit those nodes first via the diagonal step and then ignore paths with the same cost.

Comment: I made the modifications to my code, and now it runs much faster as it skips the walls, but once again it gave no solution when there clearly was one. https://ibb.co/C90bs50

Comment: It's too long, I'll put it in chunks 

```
        for neighbor in current_node.neighbors:
            if neighbor in closed_set or neighbor.isWall:
                continue

            tempG = current_node.g + 1

            if neighbor not in open_set:
                neighbor.g = tempG
                open_set.append(neighbor)
                neighbor.isOpen = True
                neighbor.previous = current_node

            elif tempG >= neighbor.g:
                continue # there is no better path

```
part 1 end

Comment: part 2
            neighbor.previous = current_node
            neighbor.g = tempG

            if neighbor.h == 0:
                neighbor.h = getHScore(neighbor, end_node)

            neighbor.f = neighbor.g + neighbor.h

        show_steps(main_grid, start_node, end_node)

Comment: I encoded the grid in the third picture, and could not reproduce the problem. It finds the path. See [this repl.it](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma635558285459839). I see your code could generate a wall in the node for the target node, which you did not indicate in the image. Possibly that could be a reason.

Comment: ohhhh, got it. Thank you. Missed such a simple point